# icmp port unreachable error message

Tags: icmp

I am sending UDP packets from one PC to another. I am watching the the whole activity using Wire Shark. I notice that for some time there is smooth transmission of packets from one system to the other. Then suddenly `ICMP` packets with error `'port unreachable'` starts to appear. Then they disappear for some time and there is again smooth transmission of UDP packets. Then these ICMP packets again appear with the same 'port unreachable' error. Then these ICMP packets disappear again and so on. And this continues in a periodic manner.

Can anybody shed some light that what could be the reason for it.

[image]

Comment: Connection quality is poor?

Comment: the connection quality is quite good. Not really sure why are these appearing

Comment: Another service may be using that port(NAT for example)

Comment: is there any cmd or any other method which can tell me that which ports are free and which ports are being used by other services.

Comment: Any body any input :( ?

Comment: ICMP is very commonly rate limited.

Comment: You can use netstat command @Command Prompt Window.

Answer (score 7):

The reason this occurs is that there is no process on the receiver that waiting on that port.

You need to have a client, that has a socket open, and has done the bind() to that port.

Answer (score 7):

One odd error that might be associated with a Port Unreachable message is seen when an otherwise normally operating conversation is interrupted by a Port Unreachable message. When you inspect the conversation you observe that the unreachable port was working without a problem. Frames were going to and from the port number when, suddenly - Port Unreachable. This is indicative of an overload condition or process priority configuration problem in the reporting host. The process in question was swapped out of memory and was not able to swap back in quickly enough to avoid the unreachable indication.

Source: https://www.savvius.com/resources/compendium/tcp_ip/unreachable#port_unreachable

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue with PackEth - utility that can generate raw packets. The system however does not know to what port PackEth will send any packets. I was sending UDP packets. So the ICMP generated by the system even thou I actually had a response from the receiver (other machine).

So I think you have an app running that sends raw stuff? or the system is loosing track of ports that apps are listening on?

PackETH is not listening on anything so I always get that response when creating raw packets, so I know that in this case I can either open nc to listen on a port or ignore ICMP messages

This is similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/949708/why-is-my-computer-making-unreachable-icmp-requests-to-the-gateway

Copy pasting that for reference

These are no ICMP requests. Instead they are the reaction to something done by your router: based on the information you show your router was sending a UDP packet with source port to your machine and there is no socket on your machine which is expecting this packet. That's why your machine sends an ICMP unreachable back which includes the details of the unexpected packet.