# Why RTSP Play Command Receives Device Tampering Packet on RTP Port?

Tags: c, libcurl, rtsp, ip-camera, onvif

I want to use RTSP protocol to connect to an IP Camera. I use Visual C++ for this purpose. I searched and find cURL library and downloaded [rtsp.c](https://github.com/curl/curl/raw/master/docs/examples/rtsp.c) from [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) site.
I used [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to convert codes of cURL to suitable sln file for Visual Studio then I created a solution and do other steps to run [rtsp.c](https://github.com/curl/curl/raw/master/docs/examples/rtsp.c) example.
Now I can connect to my IP Camera with [rtsp.c](https://github.com/curl/curl/raw/master/docs/examples/rtsp.c) and receives no run time error but I receive "[ICMP Destination Unreachable (Port Unreachable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Destination_unreachable)" on [WireShark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Destination_unreachable) and no stream receives.
On the Other side I can connect to my IP Camera with VLC Player. I changed port numbers on [rtsp.c](https://github.com/curl/curl/raw/master/docs/examples/rtsp.c) but the problem isn't solved.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522371/icmp-port-unreachable-error-message) but I don't know where is the problem? and how can i solve it?

**EDITED:**
 I used [this RTSP code](http://code.google.com/p/rtsprequest/) and [this RTP code](http://code.google.com/p/rtpreceive/) and now I Receive only one RTP Packet that contains this message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<tt:MetaDataStream xmnls:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2">  
<tt:Event>  
    <wsnt:NotificationMessage>  
          <wsnt:Topic Dialect="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tec/topicExpression/ConcreteSet">  
           tns1:Device/Tampering  
           </wsnt:Topic>  
           <wsnt:Message>  
                 <tt:Message UtcTime="2016-05-03T00:14:33.775">  
                     <tt:Source>
                         <tt:SimpleItem Name="VideoSourceConfigurationToken" Value="VideoSource0">  
                          </tt:SimpleItem>
                      </tt:Source>
                      <tt:Data>
                          <tt:SimpleItem Name="Level" Value="Trigger">
                          </tt:SimpleItem>
                          <tt:SimpleItem Name="Percentage" Value="32">
                          </tt:SimpleItem>
                       </tt:Data>
                  </tt:Message>
                </wsnt:Message>
           </wsnt:NotificationMessage>
       </tt:Event>
```

**EDITED-2:**
I searched and now I know above message is a Device Tampering message that shows an motion detection event on camera but I don't khow Why RTSP Play Command Receives Device Tampering Packet on RTP Port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) resource, several media streams can be aggregated in the same URL. Often, ONVIF cameras have three media streams: one for video, one for audio and one for metadata, to stream alerts to the client.

The media streams are described by using the [Session Description Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol), which is used by the `DESCRIBE` command of `RTSP`.

You should check how the RTSP resource is organized, probably you're receiving the packets for the last media in the session. To inspect the RTSP stream, you can use [openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/) from the Live555 project.